# 3 jQuery libraries in 1 file

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am making a webpage which has 3 jQuery plugins. Unluckily, all of them have different jQuery base libraries.

They are:

1. 1.3.2
2. 1.5.1
3. 1.7.1

When I add the following code, the plugin using 1.3.2, doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't they work if you use only latest version? Anyway, using 3 versions at the same time would 'cause the browser to download way too much data...

Comment: My suggestion is to replace those plugins with ones that are actively maintained.

Comment: That would be the best approach :D

Comment: @MatteoTassinari : I tried replacing them. It didn't work.

Comment: @Blazemonger : I'll try finding another plugin too.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari : It worked :). Tried again!

Answer (score 0):

First try out whether they are working with another jQuery-version, too.
Then you may load the first version, then the first plugin, then the following:

```
var jQ_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
```

Then the next version and so on...

Comment: Replacing it with only 1.7.1 worked. I don't know what was the mistake in the code earlier, was working on it for over an hour before posting. Anyway, thanks :).